# How can I find who made a merge in git?

Tags: git

in my master branch somehow was merged another branch that should not be merged there.

Are there a git command(s) that can tell me who did the merge and when the merge was done?

I don't have the merge SHA, in the git log for master I see commits that should stay in the offending branch only...

I've some knowledge of git grep, and I have some file names that are coming from the offending branch. Could that be helpful?

Comment: Do you know the name of the branch which was merged in to master?

Answer (score 2):

`git show` should be enough

```
$> git show SHA
commit SHA
Merge: SHA1 SHA2
Author: person you <looking@for>
Date:   date

    Merge branch 'branchname'
```

Comment: I don't have the merge SHA. :( I want to find it.

Comment: `git log --oneline | grep -i "Merge branch.*FEATURENAME"` could be useful